# On the authority of

Tags: usage

The following sentence is my grammar exercise.(no context provided in book, it is just a single sentence in which I am to fill in the correct preposition)

> I say this on the authority ______ the Oxford English Dictionary.

I know the correct preposition is **of** but I don't understand the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MacMillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/authority) lists as one of the definitions of "**authority**":

> the power to influence other people because they respect your opinions
>   or knowledge

In your example sentence, "authority" is a quality possessed by the Oxford English Dictionary because people respect the knowledge contained in it.

So if you state a fact you found in the O.E.D. (for example, maybe some spelling that you looked up), you would be stating it based on the "authority of the Oxford English Dictionary". In other words (for example):

> "Personnel" has two "**n**"s. I say this on the authority of the Oxford English Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

"On the authority of" can be expressed: [corroborated/verified by] the respected source of knowledge belonging to the OED. Emphasis on "respected." I would not cite certain news channels in the sentence, "I have it on the authority of ___News that X." Both "of" and an apostrophe + s indicate something belonging to something. What specifically belongs to X in the phrase "on the authority of X" is R-E-S-P-E-C-T.